# How can I know whether an instance implements a method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to know if an instance implements a specific method. I could use `respondsToSelector:` but it returns YES if the instance inherits the method...

I could loop through the methods of `class_copyMethodList()`, but since I might want to check a lot of instances, I wanted to know if there was a simpler solution (like `repondsToSelector:`, but restricted to the class itself...)

edit: since I really think there is no function or method doing that, I wrote mine. Thanks for your answers, here is the method if it can be of any use :

```
+ (BOOL)class:(Class)aClass implementsSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    Method          *methods;
    unsigned int    count;
    unsigned int    i;

    methods = class_copyMethodList(aClass, &count);
    BOOL implementsSelector = NO;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (sel_isEqual(method_getName(methods[i]), aSelector)) {
            implementsSelector = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(methods);
    return implementsSelector;
}
```

Comment: If you are looking to do do this on your own classes, it is a better design patterrn to use some property that tells you what you're looking for, as other tequniques are cumbersome and bad design.

Comment: You have a memory leak in your method.  You must `free(methods);`, or else you'll leak.  I'll edit the question to fix it, but FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reflection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) to do that.

Comment: +1 I can't think of another way to do it that restricts it to just a single class and not any of the superclasses

Comment: Yep, I figured, but the only appropriate function in the list seems to be class_respondsToSelector() and the discussion part advises me to use either respondsToSelector: or instancesRespondToSelector: which both returns YES if the method is inherited

So with reflection the only solution would be to use class_copyMethodList() ? Or I didn't read well enough the documentation ?

Answer (score 4):

It's probably easier to check whether the method your own class returns is the same or different than the method your superclass returns.

```
if ([[obj class] instanceMethodForSelector:sel] != [[obj superclass] instanceMethodForSelector:sel]) {
    NSLog(@"%@ directly implements %@", [obj class], NSStringFromSelector(sel));  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

instance responds and super does not:

```
-(BOOL) declaresSelector:(SEL)inSelector {
  return [self respondsToSelector:inSelector] && ![super respondsToSelector:inSelector];
}
```

instance responds and is different than super:

```
-(BOOL) implementsSelector:(SEL)inSelector {
  return [self respondsToSelector:inSelector] && !( [super respondsToSelector:inSelector] && [self methodForSelector:inSelector] == [super methodForSelector:inSelector] );
}
```

According to Apple documents you should call respondsToSelector before methodForSelector.